# How to Fix the Height of the Cropping Highlighted View, instead of changing using uploaded Image?

Tags: android, image, crop, resize-crop

I am using the following sample code, https://github.com/mklimek/android-crop/tree/newfeature_fied_size_crop.  It is giving the fixed size cropping view(i.e., HighlightView). But the problem is this highlightView is fixed depends on Uploaded image. Below are the screen shots with two different size uploaded images.

I used below lines of code to fix the size of the HighlightView:

```
 private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
    new Crop(source).output(outputUri).asRectangle().withFixedSize(100, 210).start(this);
 }
```

withFixedSize() method is used to fix the size of the cropped area , we cannot resize that view if we use this method, that is fine. But That cropped area should be fixed with width=100, height=210,It should not change depends the uploaded image.

Big size uploaded image has a small size of crop view (i.e., HighlightView):

[image]

Small size uploaded image has a large size of crop view (i.e., HighlightView):

[image]

My requirement is I have to fix the size of cropped area, I should not resize that. I searched in google world. But I didn't found solution.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

visit this :  https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

**Crop**

```
Crop.of(inputUri, outputUri).asSquare().start(activity)
```

Listen for the result of the crop (see example project if you want to do some error handling):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        doSomethingWithCroppedImage(outputUri);
    }
}
```

Some attributes are provided to customise the crop screen. See the example project theme.

**Pick**

The library provides a utility method to start an image picker:

```
Crop.pickImage(activity)
```

**Dependency**

The AAR is published on Maven Central:

```
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
```

**Java code :**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView resultView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_select) {
            resultView.setImageDrawable(null);
            Crop.pickImage(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
        if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            beginCrop(result.getData());
        } else if (requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            handleCrop(resultCode, result);
        }
    }

    private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
        Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
        Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
    }

    private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            resultView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
        } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest me where i need to change the logic..??

Comment: I done the same thing. But that cropped view size is changing depends on uploaded image. Please check the code by installing this application.

Comment: @SarithaG Make sure that uploaded Image is `fitXY` to the `ImageView`.

Comment: ImageView is not my problem. Problem with cropped are means the HighlightView in the code.

Comment: That the size of the cropped area has fixed, user cannot change the crop.

Comment: @SarithaG Used this class http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Image/crop/com_mobilesolutionworks_android_cropimage_cameraHighlightView_java.htm

Comment: That single file didn't sink with the project. Can you please upload full code.